# Generate combinations with exact number of a given object per combination

Tags: python, algorithm, math, combinations, permutation

I have 10 users:

```
id   type
------------
1     SP
2     KP
3     SP
4     LN
5     KP
6     KP
7     LN
8     SP
9     LN
10    SP
```

And I need to generate all possible combinations of 5 users, but with some constraints:

```
1. exactly 2 users with type SP
2. exactly 2 users with type KP
3. exactly 1 user with type LN
4. No user can appear more than once in a given combination
```

For example, with these ids and types, the output must be as follows:

```
1 3 2 5 4
1 3 2 5 7
1 3 2 5 9
1 3 2 6 4
....
```

How can I generate these combinations?

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, please edit your question to include your code and research to show what hasn't worked for you. If you haven't, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Answer (score 0):

With only 10 users, all possible choices of a subset of them are 2^10 which is very small number - 1024. So you can simply generate all subsets(I would do that using bitmasks) and for each subset check if all of the following hold:

- It consists of exactly 5 elements(e.g. exactly 5 bits are set to 1)
- Exactly two on bits correspond to an SP
- Exactly two on bits correspond to an KP
- The last on bit is LN

With this approach you will perform in the order of 10k operations which on a modern computer will complete very, very fast. Easy to code and not much place for error with this approach.